# Blur an image with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, blur

I want to make something like a Slideshow, but if you press a button for the next Picture, it should blur out until its unrecognizeable and then the next should appear blurred and become sharp. Problem here is, i would have to apply the blur via JS and my current approach looks like this:
`document.getElementById("no1").style.filter = "blur(3Px)";`

If i apply the blur with css it works just fine, but i need it to apply when the button is clicked, which does not work. The obejct i am trying to blur is an `<img>`

Also, it would be good to know, if there is something like a waiting condition or if additional steps in the function will wait for the transition duration of the blur to be done before starting.

Comment: do you share the javascript code you're trying to implement ? The problem can be solved faster than if you share an example of what you actually want to do as a js fiddle or code snippet.

Comment: It really isn't much more
```<script>
  function blur() {
   document.getElementById("no1").style.filter = "blur(3Px)";
  }
 </script>```

I'm building the function step by step and that usually works out for me. I also don't use external libraries if you mean that.

Answer (score 8):

```js
const img = document.querySelector('img');
img.addEventListener('click', toggleBlur);

function toggleBlur() {
  this.classList.toggle('blur');
}
```

```css
img { transition: filter 1s linear; }
.blur { filter: blur(30px); }
```

```html
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/KjUybBD.png"></img>
```

Works for me in Chrome, Firefox, Safari, latest Edge...

[image]

Comment: This does not work for me. I don't see the difference though. Is JQuery required for your solution? This is my Code atm
`.blifterimg {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 80vh;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    }
  .blur {
    filter: blur(30px);
    }`

`<img id="no1" class="blifterimg" src="blifter/1.jpg" alt="1">
`

`<script>
  const img = document.querySelector('img');
   img.addEventListener('click', toggleBlur);
  function toggleBlur() {
   this.classList.toggle('blur');
  }
 </script>`

(Sorry for the ugly Format, the comment System here seems wanky)

Comment: Works for me. Posted video in the answer. No, it does not use jquery.

Comment: It works in your Code Snippet no problem, but implemented in my site it does not work. Maybe Edge is a problem? Well wouldn't work here either then, Forget that.

Comment: Maybe you are styling images some other way. Maybe you have a `#no1` css style that takes precedent.

Comment: No, the id is just for a button, removing it doesn't Change anything. It wont even work, if i take just the snippet and put it in an empty site:


`<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
 img { transition: filter 1s linear; }
 .blur { filter: blur(30px); }
</style>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Unnamed</title>
</head>

<body>
 <script>
 const img = document.querySelector('img');
  img.addEventListener('click', toggleBlur);

 function toggleBlur() {
   this.classList.toggle('blur');
 }
 </script>
 
 <img src="blifter/1.jpg"></img>
</body>
</html>
`

Comment: Maybe learn how to use the debugger in your browser. Move the `<script>` below the `</body>`.

Comment: I read, that its best to put the script right next to the point where it is used and i never encountered a problem with this method. Seems unlikely to me, that this would cause a problem now.

Answer (score 1):

Although gman's solution is a more solid one (toggling a CSS class via JS), this simple approach with applying the filter *via JavaScript* also works:

```js
var btn = document.getElementById('blurBtn');
var img = document.getElementById('blurImg');

btn.addEventListener('click', addBlur)

function addBlur() {
  img.style.filter = 'blur(3px)';
}
```

```html
<img id="blurImg" src="https://i.imgur.com/2fGfQua.gif">
<button type="button" id="blurBtn">Blur</button>
```